# Update Navigation property When using EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How Can I Set navigation property when I'm saving models by entity framework?

I've all my models inherit from modelbase class, and modelbase class has a enum prop named ModelState.

```
public class ModelBase : IModel.IModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "唯一标识符")]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "模型状态")]
    public virtual ModelState ModelState { get; set; } = ModelState.UnChanged;

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "是否新创建对象")]
    public virtual bool IsNew => ModelState == ModelState.Added || ModelState == ModelState.AddedFromDb;
}
```

Then I found that when I'm saving models by DbContext.SaveChanges(). Not only the model(s) I passed in, but also the model's navigation property will be saved in same time.

So, how can I update the navigation property(s) when I'm saving some models?

I currently do save like this:

```
public virtual int AddOrUpdate(IEnumerable<T> models)
    {
        var modelList = models.ToList();
        CheckModel(modelList);

        foreach (var model in modelList.Where(model => model.IsNew))
        {
            DbContext.Set<T>().Add(model);
        }

        var result = DbContext.SaveChanges();

        foreach (var model in modelList.Where(model => model.IsNew))
        {
            model.ModelState = ModelState.UnChanged;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: NotMapped means you do not need to store them in the database? why you have it in the entity POCO object?!! you have theis info in the entity state if you are working with the disconnected entities.

Comment: I use the ModelState to trace if the model is exist in the database. if I using IsExist method will execute an sql query which cost to much time. Am I doing right?

Comment: the entity has a live cycle new/changed/deleted etc. when you create a new entity you know  that this is not in the database. normally you  search for an identifier in the database when you are looking for some data. You can do something like that     dbContext.Entry(ModelBase).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

Comment: Thanks, have tryed. But I need to store over 10,000 records in one minute.
And to check each model's State takes too much time....

Comment: If you have a lot of items and you want to insert them then use e.g. EntityFramework.BulkInsert

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a try!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114628/discussion-between-bassam-alugili-and-autyan).

Comment: did this solve your problem can i post it as answer or ?

Comment: yes it solved my problem.

Comment: Is it still relevant to know the state after the entities were saved?

Comment: No, I've go a wrong way on that.... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity has a live cycle(New/Modified/Deleted) etc. When you create a new entity you know that this is not in the database and it has the state new. normally you search for an entity identifier in the database when you are looking for some data. In case disconnected entities you have to change the entity state manually, if the entity is changed, like that: **dbContext.Entry(ModelBase).State = EntityState.Modified**.

If you have a bulk insertion or bulk deletion then there are many ways which are helping you to avoid the performance issues.

- 1) Use EntityFramework.BulkInsert
- 2) Disable the changetracker

and many other ways.